# Watch folder for created file and upload created file to server using Node RED

Tags: node.js, file-upload, watch, node-red

**Goal**

I want to watch folder using node red. If any file created then I want to upload that file to server using node red http request node.

I have used node-red-contrib-wfwatch module for folder watch and http request module for api call.

**Issue**

I am able to get change event on file created but how can i pass select file to http request body as form data. I have no idea how to do it.

I am new in Node Red so can anyone please help for achieve this.

Here what I want to achieve

[Structure of Node red display here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwFMx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `node-red-contrib-wfwatch` node doesn't get the file, just sends a message with following payload:

```
{
  changeType: "update",
  filePath: "/tmp/foo"
}
```

You need to use **File** node for this purpose. But before that, because the File node expects the filename be in `msg.filename` not in `msg.payload.filePath` you need to add **Change** node:

[image]

and connect the whole thing like this:

[image]

Just replace the Debug node with your HTTP Request one.

Comment: I'm glad! If you could accept this answer I would appreciate it :)

Comment: yes, sure but i have little problem while applying your solution. How can I post file or image using `form-data`  because currently i got error from api as `JSON parse error`. In back-end I use node with connect-busboy module for file upload. I got success in file upload via Postman. but not with Node-red. again thanks for your time

Comment: Good answer, but no need to invoke the JSONata expression parser in your `change` rules, since you are not using any expression logic -- instead, I would select the `msg.` pulldown, and enter "payload.filePath" (without the quotes) in the text box